# Got an error during building a RESTful Node.js API server using JSON files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got an error when building a RESTful Node.js API server using JSON files(https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/how-to-build-a-restful-node-js-api-server-using-json-files/).

I got an error at step `npm install` command (shown below)

[image]

Please tell me what shall I do.

Comment: Post your package.json, As per screenshot you are missing some open / close brace.

Comment: Your package.json file has invalid json syntax.

Comment: There is a problem parsing your `package.json`. It is not in the form of javascript object.